# How to create a simple message box with a Python script a plattform-independend way?

Tags: python-3.x

I have simple Python3-script. It is not a application - just a helper script.

Normaly it would do its job without any human readable output. But when an error happens I want to have a message window.

I know there are some unixoid commandline tools doing that (`zenity`).
Maybe there is a Python3 package doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the messagebox then you can use

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

tk.Tk().withdraw() #Hide window that appears with message
showerror('Title', 'Content') #display message
```

Comment: Thanks. Never used tkinter before.